# Google Sheets: How can I count the number of rows in a 2 column range where both cells are not empty?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have a range where I want to count the amount of rows where both cells in this row are not empty. I found a way using a third colum, but I want a cleaner function, preferably one I can contain in one cell.

For example: [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owL0v.png)
The function should return 1, as there is only one row where both of the cells are not blank.

Thanks for you input!
MSE

Comment: Please be more specific about your question, provide some screenshot or share your google sheet. And provide the desired result as well. It'll help people to answer

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A20,"<>"&"",B1:B20,"<>"&"")
```

Comment: I tried this solution already. The problem is that it only checks for 1 or the other cell. For example if you have a 4 by 2 range: {0, 0, "Name", 0, 0, "Name", "Name", "Name"} this function will give a value of 2 in stead of the desired 1.

Comment: @MSE Sorry, I think I misunderstood your criteria.  You want it to count only if both cells have something in them, is that correct?

Comment: Correct, the rows should only be counted if both cells are not blank. I tried rigging up the function by adding in an extra check for the second column not to equal the given blank column, but this gave me a wierd answer of 16 every time ...

Comment: @MSE Try my new solution

Comment: Thanks alot! Exactly what I needed!